# set-cookie field is present, however is not set in Resources/Application tab of the browser

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, connect-mongo

I got a cookie being set in the response header, however my browser doesn't store the cookie. The front-/back-end components run on localhost:8080/8082 respectively.

Using `node` v5+, `express` v4+ and tried both `connect-mongo`/`connect-redis`

`Chrome v. 52.0.2743.82`

Even though Chrome is supposed to play nicely with cookies from `domain=localhost` for quite some time now, I still tried to create a PTR in the `/etc/hosts` file like `127.0.0.1 local.com`, no difference.

Here is the set of header fields that I see in the response:

[image]

I tried disabling `httpOnly` flag, still the same.

Comment: Try view tab `Cookies` :D

Comment: Yeps :) that's where I would like to see the cookie being set, but it is absent. Resources -> Cookies, in the latest version of Chrome: Applications->Cookies

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out after reading the following article, [this section in particular](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials). Kudos to Mozilla folks!

On the node side I added:

`res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');`

In the axios.pos I added the following key:value pair in the config part:

`{withCredentials: true}`

Cheers